# How to use the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' for displaying photos from a particular album

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have setup a table view that displays users albums from the device. I'm using `ALAssets` to populate the table view.

Now how do I display photos from the particular album in another view?...

I have seen tutorials regarding `NSDictionaries`... however it needs the 'keys' and 'values' to be fixed... then it loads the corresponding data.

But is there any other way to do this..., a more dynamic one sort of... since the album names might not be same in each user's device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to go is to use a navigation controller and push a new instance of a view controller (a new one dedicated to showing albums or a new instance of the same one, depending on preference). That view controller you give info about which group to show, and potentially also hand it the `AL` stuff.

Comment: okay i have done partial work...ie embeded my view controllers in navigation  controller( using storyboard) now can u guide me furthur?